# Why is $x^T(uu^T)x=(x^Tu)(u^Tx) = (\langle x, u \rangle)(\langle x, u \rangle)=((\langle x, u \rangle))^2 \geq 0$

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, normed-spaces, positive-semidefinite, transpose

Given that u is a d x 1 vector such that ||u|| = 1 and for all d x 1 vector x,  how can we reason through the equation ?   $x^T(uu^T)x=(x^Tu)(u^Tx) = (\langle x, u \rangle)(\langle x, u \rangle)=((\langle x, u \rangle))^2 \geq 0$

In this case, x is a scalar(?).  and $(uu^T)$ gives us 1(?) which mean $\sum_1^d$ $x_1\cdot x_1$, Then since  ||u|| is 1 given. what can we say about each $x_1$
if x is a scalar, can we even transpose it ?

Comment: No, $x$ definitely remains a vector.

Comment: What do you mean by "reason through the equation"? The equation seems self-explanatory

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Can you please help me understand how we can transform from $x^T(uu^T)x $ to $ (x^Tu)(u^Tx)$

Comment: @momo mo: You can think of your columns and row vectors as $\mathbb R^{n\times 1}$ and $\mathbb R^{1\times n}$ matrices. And matrix multiplication is [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Associativity). That is why you can change the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

$x$ and $u$ are vectors. Notice that if $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$, then $$x^Tx=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2=\|x\|^2.$$ 
Then, $$(x^Tu)(u^Tx)=(u^Tx)^T(u^Tx)=\|u^Tx\|^2\geq 0.$$

Comment: ok, let say x=(3,4), then we can calculate the norm of it as $ \sqrt{ (3-0)^2+(4-0)^2} $ .  then if x = (2,3,4), we can still think of  ||x||  as  if it as the length in 3D.  so if ||x|| is the length, then $||x||^2$  is the the area ?  What when x = (1,2,3,4). know that I a bit(way) off from the original question, but any online material is appreciated as well.

Comment: Sorry, but I absolutely don't understand your question... what do you try to do ?